# Error " unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, numpy

Estaba intentando realizar el siguiente script pero me da un error en el momento de ejecutarlo, si alguien me puede ayudar muchas gracias.

Tengo una lista Bxy de 666 elementos dentro tengo una lista de 95 elementos como se muestra:

```
Bxy[0] es una lista [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,...,0] de 95 elementos
.
.
.
Bxy[665] es una lista [0,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,0,0,...,0] de 95 elementos
```

Lo que intento es obtener un dataframe en el cual obtenga la suma de cada lista formando un dataframe de 666 elementos con la suma de las listas de 95 elementos.

Al transformarlo a np.array me sale lo siguiente:

```
np.array(Bxy)

    array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           ...,
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Cuando realizo lo siguiente me da un error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Data"]=  list (np.sum(np.array(Bxy), axis=1))
df
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Debería obtener un dataframe con 666 elementos.

```
Data
0
2
0
5
0
1
..
```

Comment: Ejecuta la siguiente línea a ver que te muestra `{f"x: {x}, y: {y}" : type(n) for x, sublist in enumerate(Bxy) for y, n in enumerate(sublist) if not isinstance(n, (int, float))}`.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, ejecute lo descrito y obtengo lo siguiente: 
{'x: 24, y: 76': list,
 'x: 132, y: 76': list,
 'x: 166, y: 76': list,
 'x: 231, y: 76': list,
 'x: 636, y: 76': list,
 'x: 652, y: 76': list,
 'x: 656, y: 76': list,
 'x: 662, y: 76': list}

Cabe mencionar que mi Bxy ahora tiene 741 filas.

Comment: La columna 76 de las filas 24, 132, 166, 231, 635, 652, 656 y 662 contiene una lista como item y no un entero como cabría esperar. Esto causa que NumPy no pueda convertir la lista en un array 2D de enteros y tampoco 3D porque es inconsistente en tamaño, por lo que obsta por un array 1D de objetos list e int (tipo nativo de Python no de NumPy)..... ¿Deberían estas posiciones contener listas y no enteros o es un error? Muestra por ejemplo `print(Bxy[24]`) al completo.

Comment: Lo ejecute y obtengo lo siguiente:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [], 0, 0], tengo una vacía, debe estar causando el error.

Comment: Si, eso no debería estar ahí en principio. Ese es el problema (y las demás filas arriba comentadas tendrán el mismo)...  Si efectivamente no debe estar ahí, el error está en a generación de `Bxy`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, su explicación excelente.

Comment: De nada, he creado una respuesta intentando explicar el caso un poco más detalladamente por si en un futuro alguien se encuentra con o mismo (seguro que si... XD). Si aún no has encontrado la causa de la existencia de las listas vacías o tienes algún problema para resolverlo, no dudes en editar la pregunta añadiendo el código relevante. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error en sí no tiene más misterio:

> tipo de los operandos no soportado para +: 'int' y 'list'

es decir, se está intentando sumar un entero con una lista, lo cual no es posible:

> ```
> >>> 5 + [3, 7]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "<main", line 1, in <module>
>     5 + [3, 7]
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
> ```

La causa es un poco más complicada de encontrar, dado que en principio lo que estamos intentando hacer es aplicar `numpy.sum` sobre un array 2D de enteros que proviene de una lista de listas de enteros de la misma longitud (95 items).

Lo que nos debe poner bajo sospecha es que al imprimir el array nos aparece:

> dtype=object

esto para empezar nos indica que el array no contiene tipos nativos de NumPy como int32, sino que lo que contiene son objetos nativos de Python, lo cual dado que en Python todo es un objeto puede se cualquier cosa desde un int, list, una función, etc.

La pregunta es porqué NumPy no ha creado un array de enteros y ha creado un array de objetos (referencias). si al constructor de `numpy.array` se le pasa una lista de listas con enteros dentro intentará crear un array 2D de enteros, a no ser que se den algunas circunstancias que lo impidan:

- Algún item no sea un entero y no se pueda convertir ese item a entero o el entero al tipo de ese otro item (por ejemplo si mezclamos enteros y float el array final será de tipo float).

  > ```
  > >>> l = [1, 2, 3, 5]
  > >>> np.array(l)
  > array([1, 2, 3, 5], dtype=int64
  >
  > >>> l = [1, 2, 3, {"key1": 5}]
  > >>> np.array(l)
  > array([1, 2, 3, {'key1': 5}], dtype=object)  # <<<<<<<<
  > ```
- En el caso de listas u otros contenedores anidados, si alguna de las sublistas tiene un tamaño diferente al resto se imposibilita la creación del array NumPy con tipos propios de NumPy, dado que dentro de una dimensión el numero de elementos debe ser constante.

  > ```
  > >>> l = [[2, 3, 5], [7, 13, 17]]
  > >>> arr = np.array(l)
  > >>> arr 
  > array([[ 2,  3,  5],
  >        [ 7, 13, 17]])
  > >>> arr.dtype
  > int64
  > >>> arr.shape
  > (2, 3)
  >
  > >>> l = [[2, 3, 5], [7, 13]]
  > >>> arr = np.array(l)
  > >>> arr 
  > array([list([2, 3, 5]), list([7, 13])], dtype=object)
  > >>> arr.dtype
  > object
  > >>> arr.shape
  > (2,)
  > ```

En el caso concreto de la pregunta, teóricamente la lista original es una lista de listas de 95 enteros cada una, por lo que el resultado debería ser un array de dos dimensiones de tipo `int64`. Pero el problema es que hay algún item de las sublistas (filas) que no es un entero sino que es una lista.

Si todo en `Bxy` fuera correcto, el código de la pregunta haría lo que se espera:

> ```
> >>> Bxy = [[2,   3,   5],
>            [7,  13, 17]
>            ]
> >>> arr = np.array(Bxy)
> >>> arr.dtype
> dtype('int64'
> >>> arr.shape
> (2, 3)
> >>> arr
> array([[ 2,  3,  5],
>        [ 7, 13, 17]])
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame()
> >>> df["Data"]=  list (np.sum(arr, axis=1))
> >>> df
>
>    Data
> 0    10
> 1    37
> ```

pero si algún item no es un entero sino una lista:

> ```
> >>> Bxy = [[2,   3,   5],
>            [7, [13], 17]
>            ]
>
>
> >>> arr = np.array(Bxy)
> >>> arr.shape(
> (2, 3)
> >>> arr.dtype
> dtype('O')
> >>> arr
> array([[2, 3, 5],
>        [7, list([13]), 17]], dtype=object)
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame()
> >>> df["Data"]=  list (np.sum(arr, axis=1))
> >>> df
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "main", line 2, in <module>
>     df["Data"]=  list (np.sum(np.array(Bxy), axis=1))
>
>   File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in sum
>
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",
>   line 2228, in sum
>     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
>
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",
>   line 90, in _wrapreduction
>     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
> ```

Como vemos, se ha crado un array 2D (porque la longitud de ambas filas es la misma) pero de tipo object, en el que cada item es un objeto Python bién un `int` (tipo nativo de Python, no de NumPy) o una lista. Al aplicar `numpy.sum` sobre las filas intenta sumar `7 + [13] + 17`, resultando en el mencionado error.